# HTML Canvas - Make animations happen one at a time, rather than multiple at the same time

Tags: javascript, animation, canvas

I have a function that animates an image turning by the amount specified by the "totalAngle" parameter. The function uses requestAnimFrame to call itself until the animation is done.

```
    function clockwise(imageObj, canvas, context, angleTurned, totalAngle) {

        // only repeat if the angle turned is less than the total angle to be turned
        if (angleTurned < totalAngle)
        {
            // turn
            context.rotate(totalAngle / 180);

            // update the angle
            angleTurned += totalAngle / 180;

            // clear the previous image
            context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

            // draw the new image
            context.drawImage(imageObj, -imageWidth / 2, -imageHeight / 2, imageWidth, imageHeight);

            // request new frame
            requestAnimFrame(function() {
                clockwise(imageObj, canvas, context, angleTurned, totalAngle);
            });

        }
    }
```

If I call the function several times elsewhere, the animations get blended together, rather than completing the first one before the next one begins. How do I get it to complete the first call before the next one begins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an array and push objects onto the end of the array.

Each object contains properties for imageObj, angleTurned & totalAngle.

Have your requestAnimationFrame loop animate only the first object in the array until the first imageObj is fully turned.

Then shift off the completed first array element and start animating the new first element.